# UIWebView hiding keyboard margin

Tags: ios, twitter-bootstrap, uiwebview

I'm building an iOS wrapper application for a web page, which was built using [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com), at the top of my web app is a `.navbar` div, not fixed or anything and displays perfectly on first load.

The problem starts when I touch an input, type and then hide the keyboard. Once the keyboard has hidden the page has been moved back down, but the navbar is nowhere to be seen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this was caused by a *bug* in the CSS code which gave a margin to the body. The simplest way to fix this was to change the CSS. Although I'm still none-the-wiser as to how control the `UIWebView` in such situations.